# Copy text displayed from div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem here about copying a text that displays from div (the display comes from jquery) to another div (using javascript).

Here is my code:

```
<body onload="copyDiv();">
  <div id="first_div"></div>
  <div id="second_div"></div>
</body>

<script>
   // this function provides text for first_div
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first_div").html('Testing');
 });

   // this function copies the text that comes from first_div to second_div
   function copyDiv() {
      var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('first_div');
      var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('second_div');
      secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

My expected output is, the jquery will provide the text for the first_div, and the javascript function will copy the text from first_div into the second_div. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using jQuery for both? It seems odd include the library but not make full use of it. (Also, I would imagine the reason it not working is due to the copy happening before the setting)

Comment: Add some `console.log`s to your code to see exactly when each line of code is firing - you'll quickly see that `onload=` fires *before* `$(function()` - using the same tech in both scenarios will greatly simplify your code and life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both tasks should be on load and in order:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
               $("#first_div").html('Testing'); 
               $("#second_div").html($("#first_div").html());
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <div id="first_div"></div>
     <div id="second_div"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

By pure JavaScript as per your `question` content.

```js
function copyDiv() {
  var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('first_div');
  var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('second_div');
  secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<body onload="copyDiv();">
  <div id="first_div">Testing</div>
  <div id="second_div"></div>
</body>
```